# Callback plugin didn't work with Ansible v2.0

Tags: ansible

I am using Ansible v2.0 and using this [plugin](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ansible/ansible/83f7942dcf70f981e1dd8b1193418e416f358711/lib/ansible/plugins/callback/profile_tasks.py), which shows the time that each task consume and here is my directory struture:

```
.
├── aws.yml
├── callback_plugins
│   ├── profile_tasks.py  
├── inventory
│   └── hosts
├── roles
│   ├── ec2instance
│   │   ├── defaults
│   │   │   └── main.yml
│   │   └── tasks
│   │       └── main.yml
│   ├── ec2key
│   │   ├── defaults
│   │   │   └── main.yml
│   │   └── tasks
│   │       └── main.yml
│   ├── ec2sg
│   │   ├── defaults
│   │   │   └── main.yml
│   │   └── tasks
│   │       └── main.yml
│   ├── elb
│   │   ├── defaults
│   │   │   └── main.yml
│   │   └── tasks
│   │       └── main.yml
│   ├── rds
│   │   ├── defaults
│   │   │   └── main.yml
│   │   └── tasks
│   │       └── main.yml
│   └── vpc
│       ├── defaults
│       │   └── main.yml
│       └── tasks
│           └── main.yml
└── secret_vars
    ├── backup.yml
    └── secret.yml
```

But when I run the playbook, it didn't show the result, can you please point me that where I am making mistake.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am able to solve this problem by adding this to the `ansible.cfg` file:

```
[defaults]
callback_whitelist = profile_tasks
```

plugin is included with ansible 2.0 and as most of those included it requires whitelisting in ansible.cfg

Hope this will help others.

Comment: I had the same problem, and white listing it fixed it.  One other note I found, because it is now included with Ansible 2.0, if you put your own copy somewhere that is also in a `callback_plugins` directory, the callback will be run multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set callback directory in your *ansible.cfg* file?

If not, just add *ansible.cfg* file at the root level of your directory and specify path to your callback folder.

Because there are other [plugin types](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/tree/devel/lib/ansible/plugins), I suggest placing *callback_plugins* inside of the *plugins* folder.

```
[defaults]
callback_plugins = ./plugins/callback_plugins
```